# How to add a unit conversion button to numericInput in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app in which users can provide a (numeric) parameter in different units. For this, I would like to have an input field to fill in the numeric value (e.g. like the one that the `numericInput` function provides) and two buttons (e.g. the buttons that the `radioButtons` function provides) in the same line, in which the user can specify which unit is used. It would look something like this example:

[image]

Ideally, the values of the `min` and `max` arguments in the `numericInput` depend on which unit is specified by the user. For example, the parameter creatinine can be provided in mg/dL and in umol/L where the conversion factor is 1 mg/dL = 88.42 umol/L and the allowed range would be 0.1 to 15 in mg/dL and 8.842 to 1326.3 in umol/L.

In addition to the dependency of `min` and `max` on the unit specified by the user, I would like to be able to make calculations with the numeric value (`creat` in the example below) that - depending on the unit specified by the user - takes the conversion factor into account (e.g. with an `if` `else` construction in the server function).

Is this possible in shiny and if yes how would you do it in the below example?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId="creat",label="Creatinine",value="",min=0,max=15,)),   
    mainPanel(p('Some calculation with creatinine'),
      textOutput("creat"))
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$creat <- renderText({input$creat*100})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will meet your needs.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
  #creat {
    width: 110px;
  }
"))),
  tags$head( tags$style(type="text/css","label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle; } .form-group { display: table-row;}") ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      div(style= "display: inline;",
        numericInput(inputId="creat",label="Creatinine ",value="",min=0.1,max=15,step=0.1, width = "80px")),
      div(style= "display: inline;",
          awesomeRadio(
            inputId = "units",
            label = "",
            choices = list("mg/dl" = "mg", "umol/L" = "um"),
            selected = "mg",
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "success",
            width = "300px"
          )
      )
      ),
    mainPanel(p('Some calculation with creatinine'), verbatimTextOutput("value"),
              textOutput("creat"))
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$creat <- renderText({input$creat})
  
  numbers <- reactive({
    if (input$units=="um"){ 
      minval <- 8.842
      maxval <- 1326.3
    }else {
      minval <- 0.1
      maxval <- 15
    }
    validate(
      need(is.numeric(input$creat) & input$creat >= minval & input$creat <= maxval , sprintf("Please input a number between %s to %s", minval,maxval))
    )
  })
  output$value <- renderPrint({ numbers() })

  observeEvent(input$units,{
    print(input$units)
    if (input$units=="um"){
      if (is.null(input$creat)) value <- NULL
      else value <- input$creat*88.42
      
      updateNumericInput(
        session = session, # getDefaultReactiveDomain(),
        inputId = "creat",
        value = value,
        min = 8.842,
        max = 1326.3,
        step = 0.1
      )
    }else if (input$units=="mg") {
      if (is.null(input$creat)) value <- NULL
      else value <- input$creat/88.42
      
      updateNumericInput(
        session = session, # getDefaultReactiveDomain(),
        inputId = "creat",
        value = value,
        min = 0.1,
        max = 15,
        step = 0.1
      ) 
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Many thanks, this will work!

Comment: I did notice that because the minval for umol/L is 8.842 (according to my question), the allowed step is 0.042, which does not make sense in the real world, so in the final shiny app I will only use integers for umol/L.

Comment: Please change as needed.  This is only an example.